# put namespace in url

Tags: grails, url-mapping

grails 2.3.8 here. When i g:link to certain controller actions, i want to put a namespace in the url in front of the controller name.

For example:
    call "app/apple/eat" -> "app/admin/apple/eat"

Since there are many dynamic and static scaffolded controllers involved, I thought i can do this with some UrlMappings expression but i dont know how to do this.

I tried out something like this without no success:

```
static mappings = {
    "/apple/$action?/$id?" (redirect:"/admin/apple/$action?/$id?")
}
```

using namespace = "admin" in the AppleController doesnt work aswell

thanks for advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example

```
call "app/apple/eat" -> "app/admin/apple/eat"
```

you could do it via the grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy with the following configuration (which works than for the whole application):

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/admin/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

with this configuration, your controllers are reachable via:

```
http://localhost:8080/apple/admin/apple/eat/1

etc.
```

Or!

If you would only have apple under the admin prefix, than you could do the following in grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/admin/apple/$action?/$id?"(controller : "apple")
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

Or!

If you have more redirects, you could group them together:

```
static mappings = {
    group("/admin") {
        "/apple/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"(controller: 'apple')
        "/peach/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"(controller: 'peach')
    }
    ...
```